# Recommended FHIR type for CDS Feedback

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'd like to solicit recommendations on the most suitable FHIR type for clinical decision support (CDS) Feedback. This concept is outlined in the current draft of CDS-Hooks here: [CDS Draft - Feedback](https://cds-hooks.org/specification/current/#feedback).

The FHIR R4 specification already includes recommendations to structure other CDS concepts within [GuidanceResponse](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/guidanceresponse.html) and [RequestGroup](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/requestgroup.html). Full article: [14.5 Clinical Decision Support Services](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/clinicalreasoning-cds-on-fhir.html).

The purpose of CDS Feedback is for a user (typically Patient or Practitioner) to send feedback on a recommendation made by a CDS service. Positive and negative feedback can help the CDS service improve.

If anyone has other thoughts/ideas I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: This is a really a discussion you should take up on https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179166-implementers - I don't think it has a simple correct answer

Comment: Posted here: https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179166-implementers/topic/FHIR.20Type.20for.20CDS.20Feedback

Answer (score -1):

My current idea is to use the [Communication](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/communication.html) type. It has some very appropriate fields:

- `about`: provide a reference back to the GuidanceResponse
- `sender`: reference to the Patient, Practitioner, or other author providing the feedback
- `recipient`: reference to the Device (CDS service) which produced the guidance
- `topic`: does not have great options within [CommunicationTopic](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/codesystem-communication-topic.html) but a new value for `cds-feedback` could be extended to distinguish this type of Communication from others.

Comment: Everything in FHIR is technically a 'Communication', but I'd be cautious about using Communication for such a specific purpose.
First:
 * basedOn is intended to convey the 'authorization' that allowed the current action to occur, which isn't really the relationship between a GuidanceResponse and feedback.
 * Because the GuidanceResponse is part of the patient record, the Communication ought to be too, and it's not really going to make sense alongside other patient-related Communications.

Suggest raising this on chat.fhir.org as this is a FHIR design question and something not yet landed.

Comment: I agree I don't think `basedOn` is the best property. Updated to suggest `about` instead because I believe that satisfies the spec description of "Resources that pertain to this communication"

Also good tip to check on chat.fhir.org.